# Custom urls as filters in Tastypie

Tags: django, tastypie

Say I have a resource FOOD

```
/api/v1/food/ - this shows me all the food items as normal
```

Would it be possible to create custom urls like this:

```
/api/v1/food/complete/
/api/v1/food/incomplete/
/api/v1/food/sentback/
```

So those are just extra filters and I would have a custom view or something to handle what I want to return